# preventDefault не работаект

Tags: jquery, ajax

При выборе значения из первого селекта, подгружаются значения во втором селекте.
Но, если выбрать другое значение из первого селекта, подгружаются значения во втором селекте, но старые не очищаются

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Авто <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        {!! Form::select('car', $cars, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <select name="car_options" class="form-control">

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

сам код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('select[name=car]').change(function(e) {
        var car_option_id = $('select[name=car_options]');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'url',
            data: {
                car_id: $('select[name=car]').val()
            },
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            },
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data, function(index, car_option) {
                    car_option_id.append("<option value=" + car_option.id + ">" + car_option.name +"</option>")
                });
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
car_option_id.append
```

append добавляет к существующему, а не перезаписывает, я б на вашем месте сначала сделал бы очистку селекта например вот так car_option_id.empty();

```
        success: function(data){
            car_option_id.empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, car_option) {
                car_option_id.append("<option value=" + car_option.id + ">" + car_option.name +"</option>")
            });
            console.log(data);
        }
```

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: тогда отметьте ответ верным. незачто.

Comment: 4 минуты ждать надо) жду)